# 500 internal server error when sending a JSON object containing a Type field

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue to send an instance of this class as a JSON object:

```
class Temp
{
    public String Name = "Foo";
    public Type type ;

}
```

When if send an instance as a JSON object from a controller to a View via Ajax, I get a 500 internal server error.
The culprit is the Type argument.
If I set  type = null, the Ajax call succeeds.
If type = something else (IE typeof(String)), Ajax call will fail with 500 error.
I suppose that Type type cannot be properly serialized?

On purpose to test this, I tried to make it non-serialized with NonSerializedAttribute attribute but it did not help:

```
[NonSerializedAttribute]
public Type type = typeof(String);
```

Any idea to get this sorted?

If relevant, the view is called this way:

```
 JsonResult json = Json( new Temp(), "application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
return  json;
```

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you want to send raw json to a view?

MVC allows you to send a POCO from a Controller to a View - you can access the POCO's properties from the view. All serialization happens under the hood for you.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  Temp viewModel = new Temp {
          Name = "Foo",
          Type = new Type() }

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

View (MyAction.cshtml):

```
@model Temp

    <div>This is my name: @Model.Name</div>
    <div>Other info: 
         <p> @Model.Type.Property1 </p>
         <p> @Model.Type.Property2</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: In this case, an HTML DropDownList control from the View makes an ajax call to refresh its content.
I already use the @model into the view for other purposes.